# Https leads to exception using HttpClient

Tags: c#

I have a problem calling my ASP.NET Web API from a client application. Many questions regarding this topic were asked here but none of the answers solved my issue.

**Problem:**

When I try to call my API I get the following exception:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

**Info:**

- Both projects (cleint and API) are based on .NET 4.5.2
- In my test environment client and API are running on the same VM
- Everything worked fine wihtout https
- I created a selfsigned certificate for testing purposes but no browser shows a warning so it seems to be fine

**Code:**

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBaseUrl);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("call/CreateNew", call);
```

I tried several solutions provided in the answers of similar questions, but none of these worked so far:

- Using .NET Framework 4.6 instread of 4.5.2
- Specified the protocol with `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`
- Tried `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };` (just to be sure)

In another question someone suggested using Wireshark to further analyze the problem. I gave it a try but I have to admit that I did not really know what I was doing.

Anyway I found segments that said "**ACKed segment that wasn't captured**" and "**Previous segment(s) not captured**" of which the second contained data I actually tried to send to my API.

Can you give me some advice what to try next or how to fix this error?

Comment: have you tried with Postman? TLS12 should make it working if the issue is with TLS. REmove TLS1 and TLS11 and check it.

Comment: .NET framework 4.5.2 AND 4.6 are - old? 4.8 is current.